# How to send object by post in FunctionalTest with Play 1?

Tags: java, junit, playframework, functional-testing, playframework-1.x

I want to know if there is some way to send by POST a complete object without having to send it attribute by attribute. Actually I am doing something like this but I think there might be an easier way.

```
@Test
public void testingFunctionality(){
    Http.Request req = newRequest();
    req.params.put("user.username","my_username");
    req.params.put("user.password","password");
    Http.Response response = POST(req,"/myFunctionality/doFunctionality");
    assertStatus(200,response);
}
```

This doesn´t seem so bad, however when we have to send to our POST 3 objects with 8 different attributes, it seems like too much work.

Comment: You seem to be using a POST in your tests rather than rendering directly against a FakeApplication.  Why?

Comment: My interest is in testing exactly the method doFunctionality(). I don't know how the concept of a FakeApplication would work, could you elaborate a bit more please? (By the way I cannot call directly the method doFunctionality(user) because it will return a pla.mvc.Redirect exception)

Comment: Is there a FakeApplication for Play 1.2.5?

Comment: Oops. I've only used Play 2.x -- In that version sending a FakeRequest to a FakeApplcation makes this sort of test trivial.  I don't know the play 1.x system.

Comment: Don't worry. Now I have another reason to change to Play 2.x :)